# Bug With CSS Animation

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to implement a loading animation with CSS using keyframes. The sample code is [here](https://codepen.io/aji/pen/evMKWN)

```
@keyframes placeHolderShimmer{
    0%{
        background-position: -468px 0
    }
    100%{
        background-position: 468px 0
    }
}

.animated-background {
    animation-duration: 1.25s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    background: darkgray;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 10%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
    background-size: 800px 104px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Nonetheless, when I place the css code inside the global css of App Maker, it won't work when applied to any widget/element. The curious part is that if I put the css into a css file and use it as an external css, then it works!

I am trying to add this animation to a horizontal panel widget and I'm applying the css using the **styles** in the property editor.

[image]

When I check the developer console, I can see that the keyframe is recognized but its content is somehow stripped off.

[image]

I looked in the [App Maker group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/appmaker-users/animation%7Csort:relevance/appmaker-users/krVysM_Mn0s/xkE_EBE_BAAJ) and saw that someone has the same problem but no answer yet. I also looked in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:192783%2B%20type:bug) and there is nothing reported. Before I open a issue report, has someone else made it work inside App Maker's global css?

Comment: I'm wondering whether AM uses similar HTML sanitation to GAS HTML Service and if your css maybe gets stripped off when included in the global css? Does your widget/element show the css when inspected in preview?

Comment: @MarkusMalessa it does show the css except for the keyframe. The keyframe is somehow being stripped off. I updated my question with a screen shot for clarity.

Comment: How are you applying the class to the widget/element, is it via styles property, and what type of widget is it? Or are you appending your divs via JS when your page/widget attaches?

Comment: @MarkusMalessa I am using a horizontal panel widget and applying the style using the property editor. I've updated the question for clarity. Sorry for my poorly formulated question.

Comment: Just trying to replicate the issue so hopefully I can maybe see something. Question was worded alright.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa Thanks for your time and help. Like I said, it works fine when I place the code into a css file and add it as external css. It's only inside appmaker it won't work.

Comment: Tested 4 different scenarios with the css in global style all without favorable results. Horizontal panel with styles property, html widget with styles property, html widget without style property with `<div class="animated-background"></div>` as HTML, and using JS to create a div with class of animated-background and appending the div to a widget. I'd say at this point there is probably a problem with AM and the @keyframes property.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa I'll open an issue then. Thanks again!